# Using a single Visual Studio Setup Project to install multiple applications

Tags: c#, installation

I'm trying to use a single Visual Studio Setup Project to install two different applications(say "app1" and "app2"). When the setup runs it should ask for the user choice of app to install.If the user chooses "app1" and press install then only app one should be installed and vice versa.

Is this possible?. If yes how do i write the code for telling the setup to install only the app the user has selected?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, you have to provide a [mcve] to at least show some effort first.

Comment: i'm not asking for the code.I just want to know if such a case is possible and were to do the manipulation.